# Display Parse Object in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

Basically I need to display a parse object in a table.

My code isn't working help would be great.

HTML:

```html
<table id="results-table">
<tr>
  <th>Topic:</th>
  <th>Word One</th>
  <th>Word Two</th>

</tr>
</table>
```

Java Script

```js
$('#SearchForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var SetList = Parse.Object.extend("SetList");
    var query = new Parse.Query(SetList);
    query.equalTo("Tittle", $('#SearchTF').val());
    query.find({
        ...
    ///before query.find();
    var myScores='';
    ...
    success: function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      myScores+='<tr><td>' + object.get('Tittle') + '</td><td>' + object.get('word') + '</td></tr>';
    }
      (function($) {
          $('#results-table').append(myScores);
      })(jQuery);
    }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
    
    });
```

Help would be great!

Ben Fein

Comment: I think you're missing the form from the html in your post/code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion,

a. Add table body as shown below and set the ID as 'results-body'

```
    <table id="results-table">
<tr>
  <th>Topic:</th>
  <th>Word One</th>
  <th>Word Two</th>

</tr>
<tbody id="results-body">
</tbody>
</table>
```

b. Append myScores into the table body as shown below,

```
$('#results-body').append(myScores);
```